# Relevant Topics for Presentations

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, game-theory

I have to make an presentation as a part of our math course. We are provided relavent topics but I am looking for somethat that is challenging, related to economics something like game theory or anything that would be related with analysis of dynamic systems.
Can you suggest some topics that I can explore.
Level: relavent to sophomore/junior year.

Thank You

Comment: Sophomore/junior year of high school or college?

Comment: that's college. Sorry for being unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How long a presentation?

If you are doing a course on dynamical systems, then there are all kinds of things related to chaos is which are fun, surprising, and where the actual maths is remarkably elementary.

If it will be news to your audience, the classic Li-Yorke result from 1975 that "Period three implies chaos" is both remarkable and remarkably easy You'll find proof on p. 99 of my *Explaining Chaos*, and there's more in that book that might be interesting if dynamical systems are your thing: and of course there are oodles of other chaos-related books out there.

Comment: Surprisingly this "Period three implies chaos" been reserved/done.
The presentation will be 20-30 minutes long.

Comment: But paper can be 10/15 pages long.